# i tried to use react native video library in my project but this error occured. TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constants' of null

Tags: react-native

i am new in react native. i made my project with expo. at first there was not android folder.
so i used 'npx expo run:android' command and then android folder appeared. i followed [link](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/API.md) and this error occured when i wanted to run android emulator.

==============================================================
this is the all error text

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constants' of null

This error is located at:
in Video (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

and another question:
can i use libraries which need some changes in android folder files and any gradle configuration when i made my project with expo?????

Answer (score 1):

If you use expo then you can use expo package: [expo-av](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/video/)